# Use SQL to get the same list of function that are part of a `pg_dump`

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, pg-dump

Using `pg_dump`, we get a dump that contain function definitions (amongst many other data). Here is a simple bash script that output the names of the functions:

```sh
pg_dump --no-owner mydatabase | grep ^"CREATE FUNCTION" | cut -f 3 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d "("
```

**How can I get the equivalent list with pure postgres SQL ?**. I have tried many other answers here on stackoverflow to list functions in postgres, and I usually get way more functions.

**EDIT:**

If this is important, I'm on postgres `10.14`. This is a postgis-ready database, the `mydatabase` is created empty and then a few extension are installed (amongst other, `postgis`) and then it is initialized by replaying a dump containing (amongst regular table schema and data) a list of `CREATE FUNCTION ...`. I suspect the application to add probably a few others after running, and the list of function I get in `pg_dump` is close to those coming from the initial dump replayed.

The bash script doesn't output postgis function names.

If that helps:

```
$ echo "\df" | psql -qAt mydatabase | wc -l
756
$ pg_dump --no-owner mydatabase | grep ^"CREATE FUNCTION" | cut -f 3 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d "(" | wc -l
30
```

**EDIT2:**

Main issue seems to be in 2 parts:

- selecting the right catalog (seems to be at least 'public', and not 'information_schema' nor 'pg')
- and managing to have a SQL equivalent to the check [findOwningExtension](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/65aaed22a849c0763f38f81338a1cad04ffc0e2c/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L1561) as this is the obvious main way to prevent dumping all the functions that are coming from an extension.

Comment: What's wrong with using the same SQL that psql uses for `\df`? (Which is, I assume, what you found in other answers, but it's not clear to me what it includes that you don't want.)

Comment: @AdamKG I've edited the question to be more precise in what `\df` is not giving me the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant code:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/65aaed22a849c0763f38f81338a1cad04ffc0e2c/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L6087

See also the detailed explanatory comment ~30 lines earlier. I copy/pasted the string into a python shell to concatenate the lines, resulting in:

```
SELECT p.tableoid, p.oid, p.proname, p.prolang, p.pronargs, p.proargtypes, p.prorettype, p.proacl, acldefault('f', p.proowner) AS acldefault, p.pronamespace, (%s p.proowner) AS rolname FROM pg_proc p LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (p.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_proc'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0) WHERE %s
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_depend WHERE classid = 'pg_proc'::regclass AND objid = p.oid AND deptype = 'i')
  AND (
  pronamespace != (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_cast
  WHERE pg_cast.oid > %u 
  AND p.oid = pg_cast.castfunc)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_transform
  WHERE pg_transform.oid > %u AND 
  (p.oid = pg_transform.trffromsql
  OR p.oid = pg_transform.trftosql)
```

From looking at the code, we can see that the first `%s` should be username_subquery, the second should be not_agg_check, and the last two are g_last_builtin_oid. I did have to dig around around the file a bit to find those values (and, for g_last_builtin_oid, a google search for the FirstNormalObjectId that it's defined in terms of). The final result, leaving only the human-relevant columns, for PG 10 (differs a bit for newer versions):

```
testdb=# SELECT p.proname, p.pronamespace, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid =p.proowner) AS rolname FROM pg_proc p LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (p.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_proc'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0) WHERE NOT p.proisagg
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_depend WHERE classid = 'pg_proc'::regclass AND objid = p.oid AND deptype = 'i')
  AND (
  pronamespace != (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_cast
  WHERE pg_cast.oid > 16384
  AND p.oid = pg_cast.castfunc)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_transform
  WHERE pg_transform.oid > 16384 AND 
  (p.oid = pg_transform.trffromsql
  OR p.oid = pg_transform.trftosql)));
           proname           | pronamespace | rolname  
-----------------------------+--------------+----------
 blhandler                   |         2200 | myrole
 bar                         |         2200 | myrole
 foo                         |         2200 | myrole
 _pg_expandarray             |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_keysequal               |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_index_position          |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_truetypid               |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_truetypmod              |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_char_max_length         |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_char_octet_length       |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_numeric_precision       |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_numeric_precision_radix |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_numeric_scale           |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_datetime_precision      |        13327 | postgres
 _pg_interval_type           |        13327 | postgres
(15 rows)
```

(this is in a test db I had lying around, not sure what those `_pg_*` funcs are, but the namespace is information_schema so whatever)

Comment: Thanks for this huge step forward, the comment in the code seem to indicate that the answer is not trivial. I'm sad to tell you that this last query is giving me 751 rows. My quest is not finished, and I'll have a deeper look in the code. The truth is in the coding !.